# Should I keep my new lizard separated from the main one?

Tags: aggression, leopard-geckos, introducing-pets, enclosure

So here on Saturday, I'm heading into the town to get another leopard gecko. My sister already has two and I wanted another one - my lizard is rather happy, but I feel like he's kind of lonely, or maybe it's just my interpretation.

Since then, I'm planning on ordering a female (mine is almost an adult male) to prevent potential fighting incidents.

But if I do get a male, should I keep them separated? Please note that there are cage 'halvers' I can use to split it in half and keep them separated.

When my sister got the second one, they just slept in separate hideouts for a day, then started sleeping together the next day, and so far no fights have occurred, so I'm not sure what to do.

Any further help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gecko is a solitary animal so he will be very happy to live alone. So it is highly advisable to raise him alone.
 You must never put two males together or they will fight and kill each other. If you want to raise a couple you must take 2 females for 1 male because if you have only one female, the male may overly sexually solicit the female which may exhaust it! By cons you need a larger space to raise 3 geckos. Some raise 3 geckos or more together but I will book that to more experienced breeders because you have to have some experience. If this is your first gecko I really advise you to take just one.
Do not forget that the size of your terrarium must be 60 × 45 × 45 per gecko.

Comment: We are thinking of moving my sisters first lizard into my cage, and my new one into hers, because her new lizard and mine are from the same family.

But my old lizard and her old lizard are actually brother/brother (or sister, cant tell hers yet)

Answer (score 2):

No matter the gender, leopard geckos should never be housed together. They are a solitary species. They could end up killing each other or even if that doesn’t happen, it is very stressful for them to be enclosed with another gecko.